# How to compute % contribution to total variance

Tags: anova, variance, descriptive-statistics

I would like to determine the percentage of variance each group contributes to an observed total variance.  I would like to know the simplest way to calculate this, and to gain some intuition as to why an individual groups variance can be greater than the total variance.  I suppose a small sample has a greater variance such as if you take this data:

```
Group    Value
A        1
A        0
A        1
A        0
B        1
B        0
B        1
B        0
```

With total variance = .285, and variance of group A or B=.333

This post seems to indicate covariance may also play a role (though this is about regression) [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78862/sum-of-variances-from-regression-coefficients-larger-then-total-variance-why).

These pages are in the context of ANOVA Total Variance and percent of variance explained, but that is less intuitive [2](https://onlinestatbook.com/2/analysis_of_variance/one-way.html).  Is this the only solution, to approach this in an ANOVA context - is it not possible to use individual variances directly in a calculation of percent of variance contributed to the total?

Sample data:

```
Group   grp_std/tot_std     tot_std         grp_std
A       1.196069104         148.9800206     178.1903997
B       1.132546514         148.9800206     168.726803
C       0.706222371         148.9800206     105.2130234
D       0.94767407          148.9800206     141.1845025
E       0.905727021         148.9800206     134.9352302
```

(I apologize if the data formatting is incorrect, please let me know if there is a best way to paste a table)

Comment: In your first example the individual groups have greater variance than the overall variance only because you are comparing the unbiased estimates of the variances. The MLEs of the variance of the individual groups and of the overall variance are both equal to 0.25, so the phenomenon you pointed out no longer holds. Is the context you are thinking regarding finite samples or probability distributions? If the latter case, it seems like you can use the Law of Total Variance to get at what you're asking: $\mathrm{Var}(Y) \geq E[\mathrm{Var}(Y|X)]$

Comment: @psboonstra, thank you for the information.  The context I am thinking about is for finite samples where the data collected is assumed to be all the observable cases.  In that case, is their a better approach than Law of Total Variance?